# 20.4 - Limited to 100mbs ethernet cable connection

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am struggling with an issue where my HP G840 G1 has all of a sudden stopped wanting to connect by ethernet at 1Gbs.
The router, switch and cable work in 1Gbs on another HP G840 G1 so I don't think that it is a hardware issue. I've restarted the whole network, changed ethernet plugs and restarted the machine.
When I turn off the autonegotiation and force 1000, the ethernet no longer works and I have to restart.
Below is the lshw states that the capacity is 1Gbs but the size is 100Gbs.
Any ideas wouldbe most grateful.

Thank you

```
    user1@user1-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       produit: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 19
       information bus: pci@0000:00:19.0
       nom logique: enp0s25
       version: 04
       numéro de série: 3c:a8:2a:86:c6:e1
       taille: 100Mbit/s
       capacité: 1Gbit/s
       bits: 32 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration : autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.3-4 ip=192.168.0.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       ressources : irq:44 mémoire:d0700000-d071ffff mémoire:d073e000-d073efff portE/S:3080(taille=32)
  *-network
       description: Interface réseau sans fil
       produit: Wireless 7260
       fabricant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 0
       information bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nom logique: wlo1
       version: 73
       numéro de série: ac:fd:ce:1f:dd:67
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration : broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-58-generic firmware=17.3216344376.0 ip=192.168.0.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       ressources : irq:48 mémoire:d0500000-d0501fff
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 17.10 shows my gigabit ethernet connection at 100Mbps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025306/ubuntu-17-10-shows-my-gigabit-ethernet-connection-at-100mbps)

Comment: I don't think so because when I use another Ubuntu 20.4 portable or and Dell running Centos on the same cable, both work fine. Also, when I use it in another room, I still get the issue. For the last 2 weeks, the machine was working at 1Gbs and for apparent reason it is stuck at 100Mbs. Lastly, the machine see the network capacity at 1Gbs, so why is it blocking off at 100Mbs?